# Volume of region in $1^{\text{st}}$ octant

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> **Question:** Finding the volume of the region bounded by the planes $x=4,y=5,z=4$ in first octant.

**What I try:** For $1^{\text{st}}$ octant : $x,y,z \geq 0.$

So here $0\leq x\leq 4,$ $0\leq y \leq 5$ and $0\leq z\leq 4.$

Required volume $$V=\int^{4}_{0}\int^{5}_{0}\int^{4}_{0}~dzdydx=80$$ cubic unit.

Can anyone please tell me if my process is right?

If not, then how do I solve it.

Help me please. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me...

Comment: Yes it is correct but have you been asked to solve using calculus?